# change Right to End for RTL layouts but layout-v17 was created

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I have this in res/layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
    android:text="@string/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

and it tells me to change layout_toRightOf to layout_toEndOf and layout_marginLeft to layout_marginStart to better support right to left layouts. I did that but because of conjunctions, I created a new layout-v17 folder and made 2 versions, one for each API modes.

If I understand correctly, Android will take the relevant layout depending on the API it runs on, right? so how can I tell it not to warn me anymore about the 2 attributes from the older API (original res/layout folder)?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your android
properties->Java Compiler->Errors and warnings->Deprecated and restricted API->Discouraged reference
change this reference to ignore. If this not work some other setting will work under errors and warnings.